# Formatted String Command works in Console but not in Script.[POWERSHELL]

Tags: powershell

The script below is supposed to return formatted time in `mm:ss` integer values .

When run from the `script` , ['-f' format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)  is being treated as foreground color operator but when run in the `console` it runs fine

Also, using `System.Math` class shows the similar behaviour .

Tried script in `Powershell ISE 5.1.18362.752` and `Visual studio code 1.48.2`(Windows 10pro-64bit).

How to get a formatted result from script?

```
SCRIPT:
$global:started = Get-Date

Write-Host "Script_Started" 


Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 
    
$stopped = Get-Date
$elapsed = $stopped - $global:started 
Write-Host 'elapsed_time = ' $elapsed
Write-Host 'elapsed_time = {0:mm} min : {0:SS} sec ' -f $elapsed
Write-Host 'elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds ' seconds'

Write-Host "elapsed_time = " [System.Math]::Round($elapsed.TotalSeconds) 'seconds'
Write-Host 'elapsed_time = ' [math]::Round(($elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString()) 'seconds'

Write-Host 'Script_Exited '
```

---

```
CONSOLE:
Script_Started
elapsed_time =  00:00:03.0050257
Write-Host : Cannot bind parameter 'ForegroundColor'. Cannot convert the "00:00:03.0050257" value of type "System.TimeSpan" to type "System.ConsoleColor".
At D:\Script\Powershell\test_2.ps1:13 char:57
+ Write-Host 'elapsed_time = {0:mm} min : {0:SS} sec ' -f $elapsed
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand

Write-Host : Cannot bind parameter 'ForegroundColor'. Cannot convert value "3.0050257" to type "System.ConsoleColor". Error: "Unable to match the identifier  
name 3.0050257 to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Black, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkCyan, DarkRed, DarkMagenta, DarkYellow, Gray, DarkGray, Blue, Green, Cyan, Red, Magenta, Yellow, White"
At D:\Script\Powershell\test_2.ps1:14 char:39
+ Write-Host 'elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds ' seconds ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand

elapsed_time =  [System.Math]::Round 3.0050257 seconds
elapsed_time =  [math]::Round 3.0050257 seconds
Script_Exited
```

Comment: Change `'elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds` to `('elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the PowerShell parser sees an expression in the form:

```
[commandname] [some other stuff]
```

... it switches into something called "argument-mode parsing" for the `[some other stuff]` part, and the parsing rules differ significantly from the rest of the language:

```
Text          Meaning in Argument-Mode    Regular Meaning
-------------------------------------------------------------
bareString    Expandable string           Command Name
-word         Named Parameter             Operator (assuming 'word' is a valid operator name)
```

So when you use `-f` in an argument-mode context, PowerShell tries to resolve `-f` to a parameter of the command your calling.

Since `Write-Host` only has one parameter where the name starts with `f` (namely `-ForeGroundcolor`), PowerShell picks that as the best match, and you get a bunch of errors.

Escaping argument-mode parsing is as easy as enclosing the `-f` expression in a subexpression or a nested pipeline:

```
Write-Host $('elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds) ' seconds'
# or 
Write-Host ('elapsed_time = {0:n0} '-f $elapsed.TotalSeconds) ' seconds'
```

---

You can read more about parsing behavior in the [`about_Parsing` help document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 0):

On implementing Powershell Parsing methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7) , the following results were achieved-

---

SCRIPT:-

```
$global:started = Get-Date

Write-Host "Script_Started" 


Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 
    
$stopped = Get-Date
$elapsed = $stopped - $global:started 
Write-Host 'elapsed_time = ' $elapsed
$timespan = New-TimeSpan -Start $global:started -End   $stopped
Write-Host 'time_span = ' $timespan

Write-Host ''
Write-Host '------------------Parse Time ------------------------'
Write-Host ''

Write-Host ('time_span =  {0:mm} min: {0:ss} sec' -f $timespan )
Write-Host ('elapsed_time = {0:mm} min: {0:ss} sec' -f $elapsed )
Write-Host 'elapsed_time_system.math = '$([System.Math]::Round($elapsed.TotalMinutes)) 'min:' $([System.Math]::Round($elapsed.TotalSeconds)) ' sec'
Write-Host 'elapsed_time_math = ' ([math]::Round($elapsed.TotalMinutes.ToString()))'min:' ([math]::Round($elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString())) 'sec'

Write-Host 'Script_Exited '
```

---

CONSOLE:-

```
Script_Started
elapsed_time =  00:00:03.0062721
time_span =  00:00:03.0062721

------------------Parse Time ------------------------

time_span =  00 min: 03 sec
elapsed_time = 00 min: 03 sec
elapsed_time_system.math =  0 min: 3  sec
elapsed_time_math =  0 min: 0 sec
Script_Exited
```

Comment: `-f` supports `TimeSpan` formatting as well, input doesn't have to be `DateTime`

Comment: It's a little awkward with `[timespan]`, you need to escape non-formatting characters with backslash: `'{0:mm\.ss}' -f (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 12 -Seconds 4)`, outputs the string `12.04`

Comment: Using $elapsed = New-TimeSpan  [[-Start] <DateTime>]  [[-End] <DateTime>] and then using the above -f operator command, ' {0:mm} min: {0:ss} sec' works.